# Jenkins: Failed tests: testApp(GitProject.gittest.AppTest): connection refused(..)

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, geckodriver

I am trying to use Jenkins in combination with Eclipse and when I run my code locally on Eclipse it is successful, but when I run it with Jenkins(also on my machine) it gives me this error:

```
Failed tests:   testApp(GitProject.gittest.AppTest): connection refused(..)
```

The thing is that with chromedriver it is fine, but when I run it with geckodriver it fails. I am running a very simple code:

```
public class AppTest
{

@Test
public void testApp() throws InterruptedException
{

    String exePath = "/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/geckodriver";
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", exePath);
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();


    System.out.println(driver.manage().window().getSize());

    driver.get("https://www.apple.com"); 

    driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1024, 768));


    System.out.println(driver.manage().window().getSize());
```

Comment: Is jenkins running on the same machine as you validate that the test is running? Do you need a proxy to access internet (coorporate environment)?

Comment: Jenkins is running on the same machine